# How does the electric field behave at the surface of a realistic conductor?

Tags: electromagnetism, gauss-law, conductors

So I am taking my University Electromagnetism course and we are currently learning about gauss's law and gaussian surfaces.

A common question involves point charges inside of a hollow sphere that has a net charge.

[image: Image of cross section of sphere explaining diagram]

When we graph the electric field [there is a mild error in graph with the y axis saying Q however the trend is the same $Q \propto E$] vs the radius from the centre with the model I was taught we get something like this:

[image: Graph of electric field vs radius from center]

Noting the vertical dotted lines which happen @$r_A$ and $r_B$. This preamble brings me to the meat of my question:

Outside of this simplified model (I suppose in the real world) what does this vertical line more accurately look like, what factors control it and on the electron scale what happens?

I am a first year engineering student, so please can your answers be a bit simpler for me, thank you very much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you ask is essentially how the transition occurs from a field outside a conductor to the field-free region inside the conductor (at least in the drawings it seems that the vertical junps are at the inner and outer surface of a conductive spherical wall).

First of all: the field inside a real-world conductor is not zero *at all* because you are there between positive cores of atoms, with negative electron wave mixtures all around you, and the resulting fields can fluctuate strongly. But on average they are zero, that much is true.

If you then come close to the surface, interestingly, there are two things that can happen. Let's assume that we have negative free flowing charge, like the electrons in most metals (for holes as the free charges the modifications are straightforward). We then have either:

1. A **depletion layer**, if the external $E$-field points *outward* from the surface. In this layer the electrons are pushed away to the inner parts of the conductor by the field, which penetrates into that part of the conductor. Only the atom cores are left, creating a positively charged layer with finite thickness. You can calculate how the field will now transition in a nice continuous way, and you can calculate how much thickness you actually need (if you look up the atom density for the metal involved).
2. An **accumulation layer** if the external $E$-field points inwards to the surface. In that layer the electrons are crowding up, so they create a negatively charged layer with finite thickness. Again the $E$-field will gradually decrease now, since here again we have no infinitely thin charge layers. But here it is less trivial to compute how thick the accumulation layer will become to create the required amount of charge! Unlike the atom cores which are fixed, the electrons are governed by the field equations of    quantum mechanics (at least that is the distinction in the semi-classical description that is usually applied in solid state physics). This often results in accumulation layers being *thinner* than depletion layers, for situations where the external fields are equal but opposite.

I leave it to you to look up the details and especially the interesting implications for  semicondutor devices (like diodes, bipolar transistors, and MOSFETs).

Comment: Thank you very much, that was extremely helpful.